# How to pass internal methods as a method of Redbean PHP object

Tags: php, object, methods, orm, redbean

I'm building this new system so I decided that I would improve the base code that I already had from I course that I took.

So I started using the Redbean PHP ORM and now I'm facing some issues.

I'm trying to call the rememberLogin() method of my class User inside the class Authentication, which before I added the Readbean it was working fine but I had to do the query and etc every time.

My problem is, the rememberLogin() method is not available to me where I want to call it because, at least I think thats the reason, I now have a RedBeanPHP\OODBBean Object witch return me all the properties from User but not the methods, There's any way to make this happen? Or some other way to achieve the same goal?

\Controller\Login

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers\Admin;

use \Core\View;
use \App\Models\User;
use App\Authentication as Auth;
use \App\Flash;

/**
 * Login controller
 */
class Login extends \Core\Controller{

    /**
     * Show the login page
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function newAction(){
        View::renderTemplate('Admin/Login/index.html');
    }

    /**
     * Log in a user
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function createAction(){
        $user = User::authenticate($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);

        $remember_me = isset($_POST['remember_me']);

        if($user){
            // Now I can pass the User object as a parameter and access 
            // it's properties, but I still can't access the methods 
            // of the User class
            Auth::login($user, $remember_me);

            // Flash::addMessage(false, 'Login successful');

            // $this->redirect(Auth::getReturnToPage());
        }else{
            Flash::addMessage('Login unsuccessful, please try again', Flash::WARNING);

            View::renderTemplate('Admin/Login/index.html', [
                'email' => $_POST['email'],
                'remember_me' => $remember_me
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

\Model\User

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use PDO;
use App\Token;
use App\Mail;
use Core\View;
use RedBeanPHP\R;
use Core\Conn\Read;

/**
 * User model
 */
class User{

    /**
     * Error messages
     * 
     * @var array
     */
    public $errors = [];

    private static $User;

    // Table's name
    const Entity = 'users';

    /**
     * Class constructor
     *
     * @param array $data Initial property values
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data = []){
        foreach($data as $key => $value){
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }

    /**
      * Find a user model by email address
      * 
      * @param string $email email address to search for
      * 
      * @return midex User object if found, false otherwise
      */
      public static function findByEmail($email){
          $findByEmail = R::findOne(self::Entity, 'email = :email', [':email' => $email]);

         return $findByEmail;
         // This returns a RedBeanPHP\OODBBean Object
         // Hence why I can't access the methods of the User class
    }

    /**
     * Authenticate a user bu email and password.
     * 
     * @param string $email email address
     * @param string $password password
     * 
     * @return midex The user object or false if authentication fails
     */
    public static function authenticate($email, $password){
        $user = static::findByEmail($email);

        // Right now I have the RedBeanPHP\OODBBean Object and
        // I can access the User properties like "is_active"

        if($user && $user->is_active){
            if(password_verify($password, $user->password_hash)){
                return $user;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Remember the login by inserting a new unique token into the remembered_logins table
     * for this user record
     * 
     * @return boolean True if the login was remembered successfully, false otherwise
     */
    public function rememberLogin(){    
        $token = new Token();
        $hashed_token = $token->getHash();
        $this->remember_token = $token->getValue();

        $this->expiry_timestamp = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;  // 30 days from now

        $remembered_logins = R::xdispense('remembered_logins');
        $remembered_logins->token_hash = $hashed_token;
        $remembered_logins->user_id = $this->id;
        $remembered_logins->expires_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->expiry_timestamp);

        $login = R::store($remembered_logins);

        return $login;
    }
}
```

Authentication.php

```
<?php
namespace App;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\RememberedLogin;
use RedBeanPHP\R;

/**
 * Authentication
 */
class Authentication{

    /**
     * Login the user
     *
     * @param User $user The user model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public static function login($user, $remember_me){
        session_regenerate_id(true);

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id;

        if ($remember_me) {
            // Right now I should be able to access the method rememberLogin() of the class User, BUT I STILL CAN'T
            if($user->rememberLogin()){
                setcookie('remember_me', $user->remember_token, $user->expiry_timestamp, '/');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've add the class and methods that I mentioned in the problem, if you need something else just let me know. I hope the problem is clear